# Clear one filed of the form after submit with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I read alot of answers but all of them talk about reset all form, that I want to do is reset only specific fields for example I have  this input and this select:

```
 <div class="col-md-12 ">
    <input type="text" id="observedNEmployees" name="observedNEmployees" class="form-control">
 </div>

<select class="form-control" id="severityFactorEmployee" name="severityFactorEmployee">
               <option value="">Select...</option>
               <option value="0"></option>
               <option value="0"></option>
</select>
```

So for first one I try to clear when submit button is clicked liked as:

```
$("#observedNEmployees").attr('');
```

And second one:

```
$("#severityFactorEmployee").trigger("change");
```

But they didn´t work

Note*: Select list need to reset to first option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset your form, use the following for the respective form input options.

**Input Box**
$("#observedNEmployees").val("");

**Select Box**
$("#severityFactorEmployee").prop('selectedIndex', 0);

Comment: And i think for textArea is .val too no?

Comment: Not quite, use .text("") to clear it, .text() to get it, .text("something") to set it to something.